# Hard drive not detected after installing the Operating System

Tags: hard-drive, bios, hardware-failure, computer-building

After I failed to install SUSE Linux 10.0, I want to go back to the windows operating system again. but when I want to install windows, my hard drive is not detected, whereas in the BIOS in the detection / known. I was dizzy, his mistake about it. Where is.

I was looking for, my problem is named after the Blue Screen of Death (BSOD) that is an error message from windows to prevent further damage, but with various types of error messages, one of them as I have

```
*** STOP: 0X0000007B (0XF896A524, 0XC0000034, 0X00000000, 0X00000000)
```

I do not know, where the system is broken. but why hard drive is not known ... at the time of going to re-install?

Comment: Suse 10.0 is *really* old, and when i was using it, horribly buggy. In addition to that you *really* need to tell us more about your hard drive - sata or pata - and what version of windows you are trying to install (XP, vista or 7?)

Comment: the night before I did install Windows XP SP2. Then the next morning, I tried to install linux and failed. Well that's where the problem began. 
what is kernel dump? 
I didn't know. Can you explain to me. Thank you

Comment: kernel dump is BSOD on linux. I can try to help, but i need more details on hardware, like what sort of hard drive you have

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know now, Apparently my computer hard drive is not recognized by OS XP SP1, SP2 and SP3, due to be converted into serial SATA. But the windows 98 and windows vista can be installed.

I'm confused until now, why could turn out that way. Was it because the failed installation of linux?

Comment: If Windows Xp is not detecting the hard drive then you can try to install the Vista or 7. If they can detect the HDD then delete all the partitions and then recreate them through windows and then try to install XP again.

Comment: oh okay I'll try it. Hopefully no more problems. Earlier I almost gave up. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: If it will work then glad to help you. Fell free to ask if anything persist more. :)

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your help to suggestions above

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, i tend to wipe the drive with [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/) to ensure no bootloader related wierdness, then go one of two approaches. You don't actually need to let it do a full wipe - start it, wait 10 minutes or so, then just reboot and start with the install.

Windows XP dosen't support SATA out of the box, you'd need to go to the bios and disable AHCI, and select a legacy boot mode that will emulate a IDE interface. This is simpler, and needs no changes.

If you're a little more adventuous, you could integrate your drivers (and SP3!) with [nlite](http://www.nliteos.com/) from another windows system - since i don't know your motherboard, i'd suggest going with the chipset and hard drive sets from [driverpacks.net](http://driverpacks.net/docs/beginners-guide-windows-xp). and [sp3 from the network installation option from MS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24). I've linked the driverpacks instructions since its probably easier and better than any guide i could do

Answer (score -2):

- You can use something like Hiren Boot cd.
- Or let it boot from SUSE first, when it wants to partition your hard try to delete all partitions you made with linux and reset your system after applying.
  It should help you.

Comment: is it true? But where can I find the application (Hiren Boot cd). Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: How exactly will hirens help? *Which* tool in hirens? What do you actually think she needs to do?

Comment: O I know little what it is Hiren Boot cd. I have been searching for information across multiple sites.
In there (Hiren boot CD) No information is that there are many other tools to repair the partition or disk. 

but inside full of illegal software compilations, such as partition magic, windows 98, windows 3.1, Acronis, Paragon, and so on ...

technicians and weapons: tools & hard drive partitions, recover data, NTFS, file manager, and so forth.
But I do not know the meaning clearly.

Comment: So bad to see that my answer is -2.
As a computer professional I just gave a point.
If you google it a little, you will find exactly what you want.
But as I should explain more, when hiren booted, tryHard Drive tools, about 7 tools I think.
Partition magic for example (in old Versions).
Or Paragon partiotion manager.
Even you van boot your system with linux LIVE CD or any live cd.
Then remove partitions and you are done, just apply and reboot.

Comment: At last, I should say the only thing you need to do is to remove your partitions(partition table), and let windows to partition it.
You can do it in about 1000 ways.

Comment: yes, I think so.  Is this application (Hiren Boot CD) can really help me? It seems useful to me. But thank you for all who has give me good suggestion